# Incoming Emails are not getting loaded into CRM Queue in Server Side Synchronization

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online, server-side-sync

Recently We have switched from Email Router to Server Side Synchronization (CRM On-Premise). Switching was successful and mailbox also seems active and showing incoming and outgoing processing status as success but when I am trying to check emails through incoming queue no emails getting created and not even email message records created in entity.

We are using self signed certificate and not CA Approved SSL. can Self Signed cert be the reason of this issue?

We are using self signed certificate and not CA Approved SSL. can Self Signed cert be the reason of this issue?

Comment: Do you have any plugins for email entity creation? In the alert section of mail synchronization do you see any evidence? Can you try to download mail details, to see if there are errors or if it doesn't result in any incoming/outgoing messages?

Comment: NO Plug-in. I found the issue, The issue was with one of the setting. Under Set Personal options- > EMail-> Select Track=All Email Messages and it stared working

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, The issue was with one of the setting. Under Set Personal options- > Email-> Select Track=All Email Messages and it stared working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).